# Delete an object with a protected destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I have to write a shared pointer for class, and among many other things that it has to do is make sure it can delete the object that it is pointing to.

How can I code a solution that will work with an object that has a protected destructor?

Additionally, if the object was created using placement new, I should not be calling `delete` on the the object, as that space may still be in use (will the `delete` call even work?). How can I detect such cases?

The relevant bits of the spec:

> `void reset();`     The smart pointer is set to point to the null pointer. The reference count for the currently pointed to object, if any, is decremented.
>
> Sptr();     Constructs a smart pointer that points to the null pointer.
>
> `template <typename U>
>   Sptr(U *);`  Constructs a smart pointer that points to the given object. The reference count is initialized to one.
>
> `Sptr(const Sptr &);
>
>   template <typename U> Sptr(const Sptr<U> &);`
>        The reference count is incremented. If U * is not implicitly convertible to T *, this will result in a syntax error. Note that both the normal copy constructur and a member template copy constructor must be provided for proper operation.

The way the code is called:

```
        Sptr<Derived> sp(new Derived);
        char *buf = (char *) ::operator new(sizeof(Sptr<Base1>));
        Sptr<Base1> &sp2 = *(new (buf) Sptr<Base1>());
        sp2 = sp;
        sp2 = sp2;
        sp.reset();
        sp2.reset();
        ::operator delete(buf);
```

`Base1` has everything protected.

Comment: It sounds like it shouldn't be protected.

Comment: @Pubby I can't control what some programmer wants to put in my shared pointer

Comment: Yes you can, you can write a shared pointer that doesn't let some programmer put arbitrary things into it.  Also why are you writing your own shared pointer?

Comment: @djechlin I am writing it for class, and this is one of the test cases that my shared_ptr has to pass

Comment: @soandos: why are you writing your own shared pointer? `std::shared_ptr` handles all your cases just fine, using a deleter object.

Comment: @ybungalobill please read either the first line of my post, or the comment right above yours.

Comment: @soandos: ah, sorry, I thought "class" means a C++ keyword :). As per your previous comment, you still can do it to work transparently using deleters, unless the spec actually says how your shared pointer is implemented in which case it is impossible to solve.

Comment: The spec does say, so this is impossible?

Comment: @soandos: I mean, if you cannot implement the deleter idiom so that it would conform the spec, then you won't be able to solve otherwise. Anyway it is likely to be better to say what are the requirements of the spec.

Comment: @soandos: Good, you can use the deleter idiom while conforming to the spec. Note: the placement new in the example is unrelated. It constructs the shared pointer itself, not the object it points to.

Comment: @ybungalobill how? (and feel free to post that as an answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with the reference counter store a pointer to the function that will delete the object (a 'deleter'). You will instantiate the deleter in the templated constructor of the smart pointer, there you know the derived type. Here is an extremely naive pseudocode:

```
template<class T> void DefaultDeleter(void *p) { delete static_cast<T*>(p); }

struct ref_counter {
    int refs;
    void *p;
    void (*d)(void *);
};

template<class T> class Sptr { 
    /* ... */
    template <typename U> Sptr(U *p)
    {
        _c = new ref_counter;
        _c->refs = 1;
        _c->p = static_cast<void*>(p);
        _c->d = &DefaultDeleter<U>;
        _p = p;
    }

    T *_p;
    ref_counter *_c;
};
```

When `refs` drops to zero, invoke `(*_c->d)(_c->p)` to destroy the pointed object.

I of course assume that the destructor of `Base` is protected and the one of `Derived` is public, as otherwise the exercise makes no sense.

**Note:** This is why `std::shared_ptr` can be safely used with base classes with a non-virtual destructor.

Comment: Should work. I'll test it out later and let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of making the destructor non-public is to prevent the object from being arbitrarily destroyed.  There's no good way to get around that.  (Even if there is a general way, it's not a *good* way, as it would require breaking the hell out of encapsulation in order to do so.)

If you want an object to be destroyed by some class other than itself, make the destructor public.  If you don't, then your pointer class won't be able to destroy the object either.

Alternatively, you could make the pointer class a friend of whatever classes you want it to work with.  But that's ugly in a number of ways, not least of which is that it rather arbitrarily limits the valid types of objects you can use with it.

Comment: The point pretty much stands.  The only way you're going to be able to legitimately destroy an object is by having (direct or indirect) access to its destructor.  Even if you add a deleter, that deleter still needs to have access to the object's innards...and the only way that's going to happen is if the class lets it, either by declaring the deleter as a friend, or by the deleter being part of the class already.  Both cases would require specific changes to the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your class could take a deleter functor that would then become responsible for deallocating the object. By doing this you'd dump the problem of access to the destructor onto whoever's using your class. :)

Joking aside, if the caller knows how to create instances of the class, they should also know how to destroy those instances.

This would also provide a way to solve the problems associated with placement `new`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not part of the spec :( Are there other options?

Comment: Maybe. I think this is the cleanest. If the spec is making your life unreasonably difficult, perhaps it's time to revisit the spec?

Comment: @soandos Not really. There is no way to write a generic shared pointer that can call protected destructors because the point of protected destructors is that it should not be called by other classes. Deleters are the only clean and feasible solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your spec update I can tell you that there is no way of implementing that properly because:

- There is no way for your pointer to distinguish between the new and placement new case. The only thing your deleter can do is call `delete p`. That is *not* the right thing to do in the placement new case although it might work in your example because the buffer happens to be the right size and allocated with `new`.
- As explained in the other answers, there is no good way for your deleter to get around the protected destructor problem.

By adding the possibility of a custom deleter to the constructor you would solve both these problems.

**Edit:** This is how you would add a custom deleter:

> `template <typename U> Sptr(U *, std::function<void(T*)> &&deleter);`
>   Constructs a smart pointer that points to the given object. The
>   reference count is initialized to one. The custom deleter is called
>   when the reference count reaches zero with the raw pointer to the
>   instance.